# Behaviour of flink calling registerProcessingTimeTimer multiple times

Tags: apache-flink

I was reading this [Fraud Detection with the DataStream API](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/try-flink/datastream/) article. In the final code of [FraudDetector](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/try-flink/datastream/#final-application) class, I see below line of code to register processing timer everytime we see small amount. As per my understanding, everytime this line is called, it creates new timer (in addition to already created ones) and does not replace existing timer. In that case, I feel there is flaw in the code. I would like to hear experts opinion on whether there is issue as I suspect or may be my understanding is wrong

```
context.timerService().registerProcessingTimeTimer(timer);
```

Let us assume we receive below transactions

```
1:00:00 AM - 0.58
1:00:50 AM - 0.51
1:01:40 AM - 520.00
```

For simplicity sake, I am assuming event time and processing time are same.

At 1:00:00, first event arrives and since it is small amount, it would register timer of 1:01:00 and below will be the values

```
flagState = true
timer = 1:01:00

registered timers will be 1:01:00
```

At 1:00:50, second event arrives and since it is small amount again, values will be set like below

```
flagState = true
timer = 1:01:50

registered timers will be 1:01:00 and 1:01:50
```

At 1:01:00, ontimer will be called and it will clear the flagState and timerState values

At 1:01:40, we receive big amount, even though it is within one minute of last transaction of small amount (.51 at 1:00:50), since flagState value is set to null by onTime, it will not create alert

At 1:01:50 onTimer will be called again and will clear the values of two states, though both are already cleared by previous onTimer call at 1:01:00

As per my understanding this code will not create alert for the large transaction happend at 1:01:50, thoush it should have created alert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before getting into the detailed analysis, I'd like to clarify one point: Flink deduplicates timers, meaning that for a specific key and timestamp, there can be at most one timer. (However, this doesn't affect the scenario you outlined.)

---

The problem you've outlined does not occur because every incoming transaction clears all existing state and deletes any existing timer before possibly storing something in the state or creating a new timer.

Thus the sequence for the scenario you've outlined is this:

At 1:00:00 the first event arrives, and since it is a small amount:

```
flagState = true
timerState = 1:01:00
timer registered for 1:01:00
```

At 1:00:50 the second event arrives, and since `lastTransactionWasSmall != null`, we call `cleanUp`, which clears both states and deletes the timer. Then, since this is a small transaction, we do the following:

```
flagState = true
timerState = 1:01:50
timer registered for 1:01:50
```

Then at 1:01:40 we receive the big amount. We generate the alert, then clear the state and delete the timer. No timer ever fires.

Comment: Thanks. My mistake I overlooked the `lastTransactionWasSmall != null` condition.

Comment: Let us suppose, onTimer is called after `Boolean lastTransactionWasSmall = flagState.value();` is executed but before `cleanUp(context);` is executed, then ontimer would have cleared the timerState and when cleanUp tries to access timerState value, wouldn't it get null? If so, whether this will cause issue in deleting timer `ctx.timerService().deleteProcessingTimeTimer(timer)`

Comment: That won't happen because Flink synchronizes calls to `onTimer` with calls to `processElement`.

Comment: Thanks. In case of `KeyedCoProcessFunction`, i assume it synchronizes calls to `processElement1`, `processElement2` and `onTimer`. Is that correct? In other words, I can safely access state value in say `processElement2` without worrying about `processElement1` or `onTime` method changing the state's value while `processElement2` is being run?

Comment: Yes, that's right.